# How to find generated Link Map file in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm currently want to retrieve the generated link map file from Xcode. I'm using Xcode 10.1 . Where can i find it?

Screenshot of the link map settings:

[image: screenshot of the link map settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link map file is generated in the build path of your project, which could be found in Xcode's DerivedData folder:
`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Answer (score 0):

The directory `build/DHOTT.build/...` in your screenshot is a relative path.

The full path: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YOUR_XCODE_PROJECT_NAME-dbyywhxrphamjffeunjjdgbxoruz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/YOUR_XCODE_PROJECT_NAME.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/YOUR_XCODE_PROJECT_NAME.build/YOUR_XCODE_PROJECT_NAME-LinkMap-normal-x86_64.txt`

Or you can just double click the path in `Build Setting` and type `~/Downloads/linkmap.txt`